# How to filter rows which are blank rows from a specific column onward?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a file with thousands of rows and need to filter it.

How can I filter rows for which all columns are blank after column X?

The situation is as follows:

- I am working with a database of games and can only work with game entries which have credits available.
- The credits start on the tenth column or so, and there's nothing but credit entries in these columns that follow.
- There are many cases in which credits exist, but there are blanks in between columns (i.e. credit, blank, blank, credit). I want to keep these entries.

So far I've come up with one way, by changing blanks to 1 through find and replace and filtering the sums. However this is taking far too long and excel often crashes, rendering hours of processing useless.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you selecting only one column at a time to sort or are you selecting your entire table to sort?  If you select your entire table, excel wont care if one of the cell's is blank.  Maybe a sample image of your data would help explain.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's **SUM** function will ignore blanks and give you a total of zero for a blank row. I suggest inserting a helper column in front of the columns of potential blanks and summing all the columns to the right in each row. For example:

```
=SUM(K2:XFD2)
```

(for all columns after J in row 2)

Then you can filter by your helper column and the blanks will fall out as zeros.